# Tabs getting opened automatically

Tags: java, browser, selenium-webdriver, junit4

New tabs are getting opened even after the executing the quit() function in selenium webdriver. This happens for all the browsers( Chrome, IE, firefox). I have tried terminating the process in eclipse and also tried killing javaw.exe from task manager. but still the issue persists. Any solutions or workarounds

```
public static String quit() throws Exception { try {
APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Executing the Keyword quit"); 
driver.quit(); 
wbdv.quit(); 
APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Browser Closed"); 
result="Driver Closed"; return "Pass"; 
} catch(Exception t) { APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Error while generating the quit -" + object + t.getMessage()); 
result = t.getMessage(); throw new Exception("Exception raised in function :quit"); } }
```

Comment: Please post your code which is generating above problem

Comment: i am  using keyword driven/data driven framework. I write those keywords in excel sheets. The code for quit function is 


public static String quit() throws Exception {
 try
 { APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Executing the Keyword quit");
  
  driver.quit();
  wbdv.quit();
  APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Browser Closed");
  result="Driver Closed";
  return "Pass";
 }
 catch(Exception t)
 {
  APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Error while generating the quit -" + object
    + t.getMessage());
  result = t.getMessage();
  throw new Exception("Exception raised in function : quit");
 }

}